# Limit Goal Seek Macro Calculation to Worksheet

Tags: vba, worksheet

I'm looking for aid with limiting excel calculation to a worksheet when running the following goalseek macro:

```
Sub GoalSeekRange()
For j = 2 To 100000
Cells(j, "BF").GoalSeek Goal:=Cells(j, "AY").Value, ChangingCell:=Cells(j, "AF")
   Next j
   End Sub
```

I'm already on manual calculation, but for each iteration goalseek runs, it calculates the entire workbook, slowing down the calcution process tremendously (I know that to be true as I've tested it out and ultimately avoided it by creating a workbook with this specific worksheet only).

Is there anything I can include in the code that will restrict calculation to the current worksheet? I would much rather not have to create another workbook everytime I need to run this macro.

Thank you very much,

Andre

Answer (score 0):

House your code inside:

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    'Your code here
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

---

Also, your `Cells` are not qualified which means this will be defaulting to the active sheet. You should qualify your cells with a sheet instead of relying on `ActiveSheet`

It also wouldnt hurt to turn off `ScreenUpdating` as well. (`Application.ScreenUpdating = True/False`)

Comment: Thank you for your response urdearboy. Unfortunaly those modifications did not stop excel from calulating other worksheets and therefore slowing down the whole calculation...